# Optimizar consulta sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

actualmente estoy teniendo problemas para cargar esta informacion, ya que es bastante lento y al parecer el problema es mi consulta.

mi pregunta es como puedo otimizar los tiempos de carga en esta consulta.

```
SELECT distinct  T0.emp_pin, T0.emp_firstname, CONVERT(date, T1.punch_time, 4) AS Fecha, CONVERT(varchar,
                             (SELECT        MIN(punch_time) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.att_punches AS TX
                               WHERE        (employee_id = T0.id) AND (CONVERT(date, punch_time, 1) = CONVERT(date, T1.punch_time, 1))), 24) AS Entrada, 
                               CONVERT(varchar,
                             (SELECT        MAX(punch_time) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.att_punches AS TX
                               WHERE        (employee_id = T0.id) AND (CONVERT(date, punch_time, 1) = CONVERT(date, T1.punch_time, 1))), 24) AS Salida,
                               CONVERT(varchar,
                                 (SELECT        MIN(punch_time) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.att_punches AS TX
                               WHERE    DATEPART(HOUR,punch_time) * 100 + DATEPART(minute,punch_time) between 1145 and 1230 and    (employee_id = T0.id) AND (CONVERT(date, punch_time, 1) = CONVERT(date, T1.punch_time, 1))), 24) AS Salida_Almuerzo,
                               CONVERT(varchar,
                             (SELECT        MAX(punch_time) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.att_punches AS TX
                               WHERE       DATEPART(HOUR,punch_time) * 100 + DATEPART(minute,punch_time) between 1250 and 1330 and   (employee_id = T0.id) AND (CONVERT(date, punch_time, 1) = CONVERT(date, T1.punch_time, 1))), 24) AS Entrada_Almuerzo
                                
                                
                                
                        


FROM            dbo.hr_employee AS T0 LEFT JOIN
                dbo.att_punches AS T1 ON T0.id = t1.employee_id
GO
```

Comment: ya intentaste en vez de hacer 4 sub queries, hacer uno solo agrupado?

Comment: la converti en una sola y ahora si puedo verla super rapido, gracias bro

Comment: ¿MySQL o SQL Server? Elimina la etiqueta que no corresponda de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podemos simplificar mucho esta consulta. Esto sirve para simplificar su lectura como para mejorar su rendimiento. Lo primero que podemos hacer es mover la conversión de la columna `punch_time` fuera de la lista de columnas para no tener que repetirla.

```
SELECT E.emp_pin, 
       E.emp_firstname, 
       CONVERT(DATE, P.punch_time, 4)        AS Fecha, 
       H.hora
FROM dbo.hr_employee AS E
LEFT JOIN dbo.att_punches AS P ON E.id = P.employee_id
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(char(8), P.punch_time, 24) AS hora) H;
```

Así, ya podemos hacer los agregados. Para la Entrada y la salida es muy sencillo porque solo necesitamos el máximo y mínimo por día y empleado.

```
SELECT E.emp_pin, 
       E.emp_firstname, 
       CONVERT(DATE, P.punch_time, 4)        AS Fecha, 
       MIN( H.Hora) AS Entrada, 
       MAX( H.Hora) AS Salida 
FROM dbo.hr_employee AS E
LEFT JOIN dbo.att_punches AS P ON E.id = P.employee_id
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(char(8), P.punch_time, 24) AS hora) H
GROUP BY E.emp_pin, 
       E.emp_firstname, 
       CONVERT(DATE, P.punch_time, 4) ;
```

Después, usamos un agregado condicional que permite usar solo los valores que requerimos.

```
SELECT E.emp_pin, 
       E.emp_firstname, 
       CONVERT(DATE, P.punch_time, 4)        AS Fecha, 
       MIN( H.Hora) AS Entrada, 
       MAX( H.Hora) AS Salida, 
       MIN( CASE WHEN H.hora BETWEEN '11:45' AND '12:30' THEN H.hora END)  AS Salida_Almuerzo, 
       MAX( CASE WHEN H.hora BETWEEN '12:50' AND '13:30' THEN H.hora END)  AS Entrada_Almuerzo
FROM dbo.hr_employee AS E
LEFT JOIN dbo.att_punches AS P ON E.id = P.employee_id
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(char(8), P.punch_time, 24) AS hora) H
GROUP BY E.emp_pin, 
       E.emp_firstname, 
       CONVERT(DATE, P.punch_time, 4) ;
```

No necesitamos hacer otro cálculo matemático para la comparación porque la comparación de cadenas funcionará correctamente.

Comment: Excelente funciona muy bien, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

La solucion fue convertir los subqwerys en uno solo

```
SELECT
    T0.emp_pin,
    T0.emp_firstname,
    CONVERT(date, T1.punch_time, 4) AS Fecha,
    MIN(CASE
        WHEN CONVERT(date, punch_time, 1) = CONVERT(date, T1.punch_time, 1) THEN CONVERT(varchar, punch_time, 24)
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS Entrada,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN CONVERT(date, punch_time, 1) = CONVERT(date, T1.punch_time, 1) THEN CONVERT(varchar, punch_time, 24)
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS Salida,
    MIN(CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, punch_time) * 100 + DATEPART(minute, punch_time) BETWEEN 1145 AND 1230
            AND CONVERT(date, punch_time, 1) = CONVERT(date, T1.punch_time, 1) THEN CONVERT(varchar, punch_time, 24)
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS Salida_Almuerzo,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, punch_time) * 100 + DATEPART(minute, punch_time) BETWEEN 1250 AND 1330
            AND CONVERT(date, punch_time, 1) = CONVERT(date, T1.punch_time, 1) THEN CONVERT(varchar, punch_time, 24)
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS Entrada_Almuerzo
FROM dbo.hr_employee AS T0
LEFT JOIN dbo.att_punches AS T1 ON T0.id = T1.employee_id
GROUP BY T0.emp_pin, T0.emp_firstname, CONVERT(date, T1.punch_time, 4)
```

Comment: No necesitas incluir `CONVERT(date, punch_time, 1) = CONVERT(date, T1.punch_time, 1)`  porque es exactamente la misma columna.